# Find $x$ such that $(x^2 + 4x + 3)^x + (2x + 4)^x = (x^2 + 4x + 5)^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Find all $x \in (-1, +\infty)$ such that $(x^2 + 4x + 3)^x + (2x + 4)^x = (x^2 + 4x + 5)^x$.

What I have done so far was a substitution $y = x + 2$ which results in a nicer form of the equation:

$(y - 1)^{y - 2}(y + 1)^{y - 2} + 2^{y - 2}y^{y - 2} = (y^2 + 1)^{y - 2}$ and $y > 1$, which can then be rewritten as: 
$$ \left( \frac{y^2 + 1}{2y} \right)^{y - 2} - \left( \frac{y^2 - 1}{2y} \right)^{y - 2} = 1 $$
Also, my intuition is that $y = 4$ is the unique solution and initially I wanted to prove that this function of $y$ is injective, but it didn't work either.

Do you have any suggestion on how I can continue?

Comment: $y = 4$ is in fact the only solution to the last equation, and $x = 2$ is the only solution to the given equation.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$(x^2+4x+5)^2-(x^2+4x+3)^2=2(2x^2+8x+8)=(2x+4)^2$$

$$\iff1=\left(\dfrac{2x+4}{x^2+4x+5}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{x^2+4x+3}{x^2+4x+5}\right)^2$$

We have
$$\left(\dfrac{2x+4}{x^2+4x+5}\right)^x+\left(\dfrac{x^2+4x+3}{x^2+4x+5}\right)^x=1$$

WLOG $\dfrac{2x+4}{x^2+4x+5}=\cos t,\dfrac{x^2+4x+3}{x^2+4x+5}=\sin t$ with $0<t<\dfrac\pi2$ for $-1<x<\infty$

Clearly, $$(\cos t)^x+(\sin t)^x$$ is a decreasing function to forbid multiple solutions

**Generalization** : $$\left(\dfrac{2x+4}{x^2+4x+5}\right)^y+\left(\dfrac{x^2+4x+3}{x^2+4x+5}\right)^y=1$$

$\implies y=2$

Comment: The only thing unclear to me is when you say that the function $g(x) = (cos t)^x + (sin t)^x$ is a decreasing function, as $t$ also depends on $x$, so you cannot treat $t$ as a constant.

Comment: @Sandel, For $0\le y\le1,  y^x$ is decreasing right?

Comment: Yes, I agree with that part.