# Solving $(x^2+4x+3)^x+(2x+4)^x=(x^2+4x+5)^x$ with $x\in(-1,\infty)$

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, contest-math

I've been struggling for a few hours on the below pre-calculus olympiad equation to which I still don't have an answer:

> $$(x^2+4x+3)^x+(2x+4)^x=(x^2+4x+5)^x$$
>   where $x \in (-1,\infty)$.

Now, according to WolframAlpha, this has a unique solution, $x=2$, and I need to prove this for one of my student without using derivatives or any more advanced techniques.

Interesting substitutions that I've tried, but with no success:

1) $a=(x+2)-\frac{1}{x+2}, b=(x+2)-\frac{1}{x+2}$ leads to 
$$(b^2-a^2)^x=(b^x-a^x)^2$$

2) $\alpha =2\arctan(x+2)$ leads to 
$$(-\cos(\alpha ))^{\tan(\alpha /2)-2} + (\sin(\alpha ))^{\tan(\alpha /2)-2} = 1$$

Both of them make the solution $x=2$ easy to see, but its unicity still eludes me.

Comment: A quick check verifies that $x=0$ and $x=1$ are not solutions. All other integers in the range are excluded by FLT, though this is arguably more advanced than derivatives.

Comment: I thought it was clear from the interval notation, the equation needs to be solved for a real number x.

Comment: @Kronecker Can I use $y=a^x$ is strictly increasing or decresing? If so, I might have an answer.

Comment: @StAKmod You can; however I tried using monotony to prove unicity in various ways, but always something wasn't adding up; either it was increasing*decreasing or some negative values and powers broke things. In addition, I did always check the derivatives and WolframAlpha and nothing that could apparently be easily shown to be monotonous by means of composition of monotonous functions was actually monotonous on the full set of values.

Comment: @Kronecker Just typing my solution.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3052915/find-x-such-that-x2-4x-3x-2x-4x-x2-4x-5x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the trivial solution is $x=2$.

Then, consider the fact $$(x^2+4x+3)^2+(2x+4)^2=(x^2+4x+5)^2 \tag{1}$$

And the fact $\dfrac{x^2+4x+3}{x^2+4x+5}$ and $\dfrac{2x+4}{x^2+4x+5}$ are both in $(0,1)$ if $x \in (-1,\infty)$. (I believe you can figure this out yourself.)

Consider that $a^x$ is strictly decreasing if $a\in (0,1)$.

We can easily get 
$$\left({x^2+4x+3\over x^2+4x+5}\right)^x \gt \left({x^2+4x+3\over x^2+4x+5}\right)^2 \tag{2}$$ if $x\in (-1,2)$, and other cases.

We have:

Case:$x\in (-1,2)$, then 
$$\left({x^2+4x+3\over x^2+4x+5}\right)^x+\left({2x+4\over x^2+4x+5}\right)^x \gt \left({x^2+4x+3\over x^2+4x+5}\right)^2+\left({2x+4\over x^2+4x+5}\right)^2=1 \tag{3}$$.

In another case ($x\in (2, \infty)$), we have
$$\left({x^2+4x+3\over x^2+4x+5}\right)^x+\left({2x+4\over x^2+4x+5}\right)^x \lt \left({x^2+4x+3\over x^2+4x+5}\right)^2+\left({2x+4\over x^2+4x+5}\right)^2=1 \tag{4}$$

Hence, the only solution is $x=2$.

Comment: This was my first thought, but actually $\left(\frac{2x+4}{x^2+4x+5}\right)^x$ isn't monotonous on $(-1,0)$. You can easily check that on WolframAlpha

Comment: @Kronecker Read my solution carefully, I did not say it is monotonous, but we do have that bigger than power 2.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. I was blinded by looking at overall monotony, but indeed using the first relation which works for all $x$, it's enough to derive the inequality from just the exponent. Your solution seems flawless. Thanks

Comment: @Kronecker Yeah, sometimes we are just missing in the complex way of solving problems, that is one of the main problems in math.